# Assign correct Responsible person from JSON format column based on Service Date

Tags: json, sql-server, date, join, case

**P.S. previous post was deleted, I hope this time it will reach more people.**

I have huge history dataset and I need to assign value (ResponsibleName - from JSON format column) to a new 'Responsible' column based on Service Date for all rows associate with Client.

Each **Client** can have unique **Responsible** person (JSON column) for the specific date range:

1. If Codes Column contains Supervisor, then assign this Employee to only associated row as Responsible.
2. And finally, if Codes Column contains Employee, than assign associated Responsible person from the JSON column (for specific date range) to Responsible

I don't have issues with the first step, however I can't find a solution to implement the 2nd (last) statement.

Original History Table Joined with Client Table:

```
SELECT h.Id,
       h.ServiceDate
       h.ClientId,
       cl.ClientName,
       h.EmployeeName,
       cl.ResponsibleJSON,
       h.Codes
FROM History AS h
JOIN ClientTable AS cl
   ON (h.ClientId = cl.ClientId)
```

Output of that table:

| Id | ServiceDate | ClientId | ClientName | EmployeeName | ResponsibleJSON | Codes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-05-06 | 123 | John Smith | Chris Evans | [{"ResponsibleName":"Kevin Costner","ResponsibleStartDate":"2019-02-14","ResponsibleEndDate":"2020-05-31"},{"ResponsibleName":"Tom Cruise", "ResponsibleStartDate":"2020-06-01","ResponsibleEndDate":null}] | Employee, Office |
| 2 | 2020-05-08 | 123 | John Smith | Tom Holland | [{"ResponsibleName":"Kevin Costner","ResponsibleStartDate":"2019-02-14","ResponsibleEndDate":"2020-05-31"},{"ResponsibleName":"Tom Cruise", "ResponsibleStartDate":"2020-06-01","ResponsibleEndDate":null}] | Supervisor, Remote |
| 3 | 2020-05-11 | 123 | John Smith | Chris Evans | [{"ResponsibleName":"Kevin Costner","ResponsibleStartDate":"2019-02-14","ResponsibleEndDate":"2020-05-31"},{"ResponsibleName":"Tom Cruise", "ResponsibleStartDate":"2020-06-01","ResponsibleEndDate":null}] | Employee, Office |
| 4 | 2020-05-15 | 123 | John Smith | Thomas Anderson | [{"ResponsibleName":"Kevin Costner","ResponsibleStartDate":"2019-02-14","ResponsibleEndDate":"2020-05-31"},{"ResponsibleName":"Tom Cruise", "ResponsibleStartDate":"2020-06-01","ResponsibleEndDate":null}] | Employee, Office |
| 5 | 2020-06-10 | 123 | John Smith | Tom Holland | [{"ResponsibleName":"Kevin Costner","ResponsibleStartDate":"2019-02-14","ResponsibleEndDate":"2020-05-31"},{"ResponsibleName":"Tom Cruise", "ResponsibleStartDate":"2020-06-01","ResponsibleEndDate":null}] | Supervisor, Office |
| 6 | 2020-06-17 | 123 | John Smith | Thomas Anderson | [{"ResponsibleName":"Kevin Costner","ResponsibleStartDate":"2019-02-14","ResponsibleEndDate":"2020-05-31"},{"ResponsibleName":"Tom Cruise", "ResponsibleStartDate":"2020-06-01","ResponsibleEndDate":null}] | Employee, Remote |
| 7 | 2020-06-22 | 123 | John Smith | Elon Mask | [{"ResponsibleName":"Kevin Costner","ResponsibleStartDate":"2019-02-14","ResponsibleEndDate":"2020-05-31"},{"ResponsibleName":"Tom Cruise", "ResponsibleStartDate":"2020-06-01","ResponsibleEndDate":null}] | Employee, Remote |
| 8 | 2020-07-01 | 123 | John Smith | Tom Holland | [{"ResponsibleName":"Kevin Costner","ResponsibleStartDate":"2019-02-14","ResponsibleEndDate":"2020-05-31"},{"ResponsibleName":"Tom Cruise", "ResponsibleStartDate":"2020-06-01","ResponsibleEndDate":null}] | Supervisor, Remote |

I've created the table with all JSON data for all Clients:

```
SELECT  c.ClientId,
        c.ClientFullName,
        c.ResponsibleJSON,
        JSON_VALUE(X.VALUE,'$.ResponsibleName') AS ResponsibleName,
        JSON_VALUE(X.VALUE,'$.ResponsibleStartDate') AS ResponsibleStartDate,
        ISNULL(JSON_VALUE(X.VALUE,'$.ResponsibleEndDate'), '2999-12-31') AS ResponsibleEndDate

FROM ClientTable AS c
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(c.ResponsibleJSON) AS X
ORDER BY c.ClientFullName, ResponsibleStartDate
```

And now I need to combine them somehow to produce column below:

Desired Output:

| Responsible |
| --- |
| Kevin Costner |
| Tom Holland |
| Kevin Costner |
| Kevin Costner |
| Tom Holland |
| Tom Cruise |
| Tom Cruise |
| Tom Holland |

Code I need help with you can find below.
I don't know if I can OUTER APPLY in CASE statement AND I think JOIN should be ON ClientId and check if ServiceDate between ResponsibleStartDate AND ResponsibleEndDate.

```
SELECT h.Id,
       h.ServiceDate
       h.ClientId,
       cl.ClientName,
       h.EmployeeName,
       cl.ResponsibleJSON,
       h.Codes,

       CASE
          WHEN h.Codes LIKE '%Supervisor%' THEN h.EmployeeName --- 1st statement
          WHEN --- here should be the second statement. I don't know how to implement it.
       END AS Responsible

FROM History AS h
JOIN ClientTable AS cl
   ON (h.ClientId = cl.ClientId)
```

Comment: *"previous post was deleted, I hope this time it will reach more people."* reposting a question is generally not well received. if you want a question to get more attention, bounty it.

Comment: Thank You, for advice, @Laurnu. Didn’t know about it. Will do next time

Comment: This is the second time you have deleted and reposted. Be careful, you are probably heading for automatic ban

Comment: @Charlieface, I will keep it in mind. No more deletions. Thank You

Comment: I don't get  the logic: how does `Tom Holland` end up in the results if they're not present in `ResponsibleJSON`? And what happend to all those columns, you only show one column from your expected results, how does it correlate to the first table?

Comment: Tom Holland doesn't need to be in ResponsibleJSON. Tom Holland just a supervisor associated with Client for that specific service date. You can treat ResponsibleJSON like list of directors. And I mentioned the CASE WHEN h.Codes LIKE '%Supervisor%' THEN h.EmployeeName. So if Supervisor associate with Client, Supervisor is responsible, if just employee, then Director from JSON column. Hope it make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you only want to lookup the JSON when the `Codes` column does not contain `Supervisor`. The following query should do what you want:

```sql
SELECT
  c.Id,
  c.ServiceDate,
  c.ClientId,
  c.ClientName,
  c.EmployeeName,
  c.Codes,
  Supervisor =
      CASE WHEN c.Codes LIKE '%Supervisor%' THEN c.EmployeeName
      ELSE (
          SELECT TOP (1)
            j.ResponsibleName
          FROM OPENJSON(c.ResponsibleJSON)
            WITH (
              ResponsibleName nvarchar(100),
              ResponsibleStartDate date,
              ResponsibleEndDate date
            ) j
          WHERE c.ServiceDate >= j.ResponsibleStartDate
            AND (j.ResponsibleEndDate IS NULL OR c.ServiceDate <= j.ResponsibleEndDate)
      )
      END
FROM ClientTable c;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0cfc457912cb167713a96fa729bbee8a)